# How to center an image vertically on the balance of the space left on a page (less navbar/header & footer) and have a background image?

Tags: html, css

I see that this question has been asked before but with different elements used. I want the *balance of space that is left (less header and footer space) to have the image smack in the middle* no matter the size of the viewer's screen / browser.
I've tried sooooo many codes that I've read here but always either
a. something becomes messed up on the page and/or
b. the image still isn't vertically centered on the **page** itself (unless the page itself doesn't contain all my bits) though fixes center it in the middle of a space allocated but that space isn't centered vertically on the page.

EDIT NOTE: The answers below by roopa *only resolved the Footer issue* that I had included in this post as vertically centered image fixes I tried messed it up too.

EDIT 2: I have found the solution and have posted it as an Answer.

Thank you.

Here are the current codes: http://jsbin.com/vazevamile/edit?html,output

And a Stack Snippet:

```css
/* chrome android to show background-image */
html{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 50px; /* Padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Change value if navbar height changes. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. */
 font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif, calibri, "lucida sans", verdana, arial, monospace;
 font-size: 12px;
/* chrome android to show background-image */
  min-height:100%;
/* .end */
/*keep footer at bottom*/
  height:100%;
  margin:0; /* for footer*/
/* .end*/
  padding: 0 2em; /* top, right, bottom, and left*/
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #B4A890;
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Fall-Nature-Background-Pictures.jpg");
  background-position:absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* resize images as windows shrinks */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

/* CSSReset.com - How To Keep Footer At Bottom of Page with CSS
 * http://www.cssreset.com/2010/css-tutorials/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/*/
#wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
#header {
 background:#ededed;
 padding:0px;
}

    }
    #content {
          position:relative;
padding:50px 0;
        /*background-color:black; - for testing*/
    }
 
/* orginal, before footer background fix:
#content {
 padding:50px; /*padding for navbar at the top*/
/* padding-bottom:100px; /*value must be equal to or greater than the height of #footer*/
 /*background-color:black; - for testing*/
/*}*/

#footer {
 background:#000000;
 width:100%;
 min-height:100px; /*for footer background fix*/
 /*height:100px; - orginal before footer background fix*/
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en">

<head>
    <!-- MenuBar - below 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- ./3 meta tags -->
 
    <!-- MenuBar - Bootstrap Core CSS (ddmenu.js, jquery.js & bootstrap.js are the bottom for faster loading)-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
   <!-- MenuBar & Mine Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css-mb/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- /.custom css -->  

 

  

 
 
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]--> 
 
<!--for footer bottom:-->
 <!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
   #wrapper { height:100%; }
  </style>
 <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="header">
<!-- MenuBar Navigation  -->
    <a id="ddmenuLink" href="menu_bar.htm">Menu</a>
     <script src="js-mb/jsfiddle.js"></script>
<!--   /.navigation  -->
  </div><!--.header-->

  <div id="content">
  <center><img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/k3sz9x.jpg" width="840" height="166"></center>
  </div><!--.content-->
  
  <div id="footer">
  <center><TABLE BORDER=0><TR>
<TD><b><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque venenatis ante vitae interdum feugiat. Duis pretium diam quis justo fermentum efficitur. Pellentesque justo tortor, vulputate quis suscipit ut, lobortis eu massa. Donec vitae nisi sagittis, dictum eros pulvinar, finibus turpis. Nullam</center></b></TD>
</TR></TABLE></center>
<p><center><b>FOOTER</b></center></p>
  </div><!--.footer-->
  

</div><!--.wrapper-->


<!-- MenuBar - jQuery & JavaScript are required for the dropdown menu. Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492400858966.txt" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m having a mini CSS celebration here ;) . I woke up in the middle of the night and realized I was going about it the wrong way. The image couldn’t center as it didn’t know the size of the container to be center in. 
1. So first I needed to have a container that would take up the balance of the empty space no matter the size of the window (found here: http://jsfiddle.net/WdrDH/ ):

```
/* Height less (header + footer) */
section {
  height: calc(100% - (50px + 25px)); 
}
```

2. Then to center the image, any size image (found here http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/kzEhe and here: [css3: translateX to center element horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538718/css3-translatex-to-center-element-horizontally) ):

```
.image img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%);
}
```

You'll need this too:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

html part for section and image:

```
<section class="image">
<img src="https://yourimage.com/image.jpg" width="840" height="166">
</section>
```

I've included all my other bits (menu, background image, etc.) to demonstrate they aren't messed up. Find here https://jsfiddle.net/4dcuaen2/ and below:

```css
/* chrome android to display background-image */
html{
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 50px 20px 0px 20px;/* 50px: for .navbar-fixed-top.*/
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif, calibri, "lucida sans", verdana, arial, monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
/* chrome android to dispaly background-image */
  min-height:100%;
/* .end */
/*keep footer at bottom*/
  height:100%;
  margin:0; /* for footer*/
/* .end*/
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #B4A890;
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Fall-Nature-Background-Pictures.jpg");
  background-position:absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* RELEVANT CODE TO CENTERING AN IMAGE HORIZONTALLY & VERTICALLY NO MATTER THE SIZE OF THE WINDOW: */
/* 1. Container to use balance of the space: */
/* Height less (header + footer). 
(Note: My footer is 70, but if use 70 it places extra space below footer and the need to scroll even if window is larger.) */
section {
  height: calc(100% - (50px + 25px)); 
/* Container border for visual testing*/
  border: 2px solid red;
}

/* 2. Center image vertically & horizontally */
.image img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%);
}
/* .END OF RELEVANT CODE */

/* resize images as windows shrinks */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

#footer {
  width:100%;
  min-height:70px; /*for footer background fix*/
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  font-size: 13px;
/* Container border for visual testing*/
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.foot {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size:13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en">

<head>
    <!-- MenuBar - below 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- ./3 meta tags -->
<title>CENTERED</title> 
    <!-- MenuBar - Bootstrap Core CSS (ddmenu.js, jquery.js & bootstrap.js are the bottom for faster loading)-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
   <!-- MenuBar & Mine Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css-mb/main-SOLVED.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- /.custom css -->  
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header"> <!--This div creates a navigation button visible on smaller screens -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--These tags create the standard 3-lin button logo on top right corner -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--Put the page less than full-screen to see this behavior -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1<span class="caret"></span></a><!--Requires the JavaScript files linked at the end-->
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">AnotherItem</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Header:</li>
                            <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav> 
  
  
<section class="image">
<img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/k3sz9x.jpg" width="840" height="166">
</section>


   <div id="footer">
  <center>
<TABLE BORDER=0><TR id="sl">
<TD><a href="#" target="_blank" class="tm-social-link"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-facebook"></i>FB</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD><a href="#" target="_blank" class="tm-social-link"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-youtube"></i>YT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD><a href="#"<span class="st_sharethis_custom" st_via="XXX" st_msg="#XXX"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-share-alt"></i>SH</a></span></TD>
</TR></TABLE>
</center>
<div class="foot">FOOTER TEXT</div><!--class foot-->
  </div><!--.footer-->


<!-- MenuBar - jQuery & JavaScript are required for the dropdown menu. Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492400858966.txt" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have checked this code in my local server and footer is working fine as per your requirement.
So please implement it and let me know how is this working.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
    <meta http-equiv="language" content="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    

        <link href="css-mb/main.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <style>


    body {
        padding-top: 50px; /* Padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Change value if navbar height changes. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. */
        font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif, calibri, "lucida sans", verdana, arial, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
      min-height:100%;
      height:100%;
      margin:0; /* for footer*/
    /* .end*/
      padding: 0 2em; /* top, right, bottom, and left*/
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        color: #ffff;
  background-color: #B4A890;
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Fall-Nature-Background-Pictures.jpg");
  background-position:absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;

    }

    /* resize images as windows shrinks */
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    }

    #wrapper {
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    #header {
        background:#ededed;
        padding:0px;
    }
    #content { 
  padding: 0; 
  display: table; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 520px;
 } 
 #content center{ 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
 } 
    #footer {
        background:#000000;
        width:100%;
        min-height:50px;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        font-size: 15px;
  position: fixed;
    }
        </style>
  
  
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">  
            <div id="header">
    <!-- MenuBar Navigation  -->
        <a id="ddmenuLink" href="menu_bar.htm">Menu</a>
            <script src="js-mb/jsfiddle.js"></script>
    <!--   /.navigation  -->
            </div><!--.header-->

            <div id="content">
            <center><img src="http://r69.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext240617569866922.png" class="img-resposive" ></center>
            </div><!--.content-->

            <div id="footer">
            <center>
   <TABLE BORDER=0>
   <TR>
            <TD><b><center>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br></TD>
   </TR>
   </TABLE>
   </center>
   <p><center><b>FOOTER</b></center></p>
            </div><!--.footer-->


    </div><!--.wrapper-->


    <!-- MenuBar - jQuery & JavaScript are required for the dropdown menu. Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492400858966.txt" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For the image verticle alignment issue. I am trying to implement a perfect solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Beautiful, yes Footer is working perfect. Thank you very much roopa. 
Vertical centered image - no rush, no pressure :) 
I've put it here <http://jsbin.com/lemavivoyu/edit?html,output>

Comment: Thanks for your comment. and can you please accept as your answer.

Comment: Roopa a bit confused as the main issue to vertically align the image isn't resolved yet or did I miss something? Here is the latest code you gave me (I had to change URL of the image as they took it off line):
http://jsbin.com/qoweguneme/edit?html,output
What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below mentioned code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
    <meta http-equiv="language" content="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    

        <link href="css-mb/main.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <style>


    body {
        padding-top: 50px; /* Padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Change value if navbar height changes. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. */
        font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif, calibri, "lucida sans", verdana, arial, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
    /* chrome android to show background-image */
      min-height:100%;
    /* .end */
    /*keep footer at bottom*/
      height:100%;
      margin:0; /* for footer*/
    /* .end*/
      padding: 0 2em; /* top, right, bottom, and left*/
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
      color: #ffff;

    }

    /* resize images as windows shrinks */
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    }

    #wrapper {
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    #header {
        background:#ededed;
        padding:0px;
    }
    #content {
          position:relative;
padding:50px 0;
        /*background-color:black; - for testing*/
    }
    #footer {
        background:#000000;
        width:100%;
        min-height:100px;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">  
            <div id="header">
    <!-- MenuBar Navigation  -->
        <a id="ddmenuLink" href="menu_bar.htm">Menu</a>
            <script src="js-mb/jsfiddle.js"></script>
    <!--   /.navigation  -->
            </div><!--.header-->

            <div id="content">
            <center><img src="http://r69.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext240617569866922.png" class="img-resposive" ></center>
            </div><!--.content-->

            <div id="footer">
            <center><TABLE BORDER=0><TR>
    <TD><b><center>1. Problem: Image Above - Can't center vertically.<br>
    2. Problem: This Footer - Background is fixed (100px), when screen is smaller (collapsed) the footer background isn't tall enough to cover the collapsed footer text. (If I use width 100% & 'margin:auto;' the text is fixed and won't collapse on smaller screens.)</center></b></TD>
    </TR></TABLE></center>
    <p><center><b>FOOTER</b></center></p>
            </div><!--.footer-->


    </div><!--.wrapper-->


    <!-- MenuBar - jQuery & JavaScript are required for the dropdown menu. Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492400858966.txt" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Footer problem resolved - thank you so very much for your time and reply roopa mishra! :) 

Image vertically centered still not resolved. I'll edit my original post to clarify footer problem resolved.

Comment: For a vertically fixed image in middle need to give a fixed height and in a parent section.

Comment: So can i send you a css according to your html code. I hope it is right for you as per your requirement

Comment: #content {
  padding: 0;
  height: 350px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
 }  
 #content center{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

Comment: Thank you again roopa. I think my brain has become mush as I can't quite figure out how to use it. It has only aligned it to the left. This is what I have done:
html changes:
  `<div id="content">
  <div id="content center">
  <center><img src="img/theimage.png" width="882" height="169"></center>
  </div>
  </div>`

css changes:
   ` #content {
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 169px; /*height of my image*/
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    }

    #content center{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }`

Comment: Okay I am checking and let you back within few minutes

Comment: any luck roopa? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    

    <link href="css-mb/main.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <style>


body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* Padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Change value if navbar height changes. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. */
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif, calibri, "lucida sans", verdana, arial, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0; /* for footer*/
/* .end*/
  padding: 0 2em; /* top, right, bottom, and left*/
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #ffff;

}

/* resize images as windows shrinks */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:0px;
}
#content { 
    padding: 0; 
    height: 300px; 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
} 
#content center{ 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
} 
#footer {
    background:#000000;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div id="header">
<!-- MenuBar Navigation  -->
    <a id="ddmenuLink" href="menu_bar.htm">Menu</a>
        <script src="js-mb/jsfiddle.js"></script>
<!--   /.navigation  -->
        </div><!--.header-->

        <div id="content">
        <center><img src="http://r69.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext240617569866922.png" class="img-resposive" ></center>
        </div><!--.content-->

        <div id="footer">
        <center>
        <TABLE BORDER=0>
        <TR>
        <TD><b><center>1. Problem: Image Above - Can't center vertically.<br>
2. Problem: This Footer - Background is fixed (100px), when screen is smaller (collapsed) the footer background isn't tall enough to cover the collapsed footer text. (If I use width 100% & 'margin:auto;' the text is fixed and won't collapse on smaller screens.)</center></b>
        </TD>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
        </center>
        <p><center><b>FOOTER</b></center></p>
        </div><!--.footer-->


</div><!--.wrapper-->


<!-- MenuBar - jQuery & JavaScript are required for the dropdown menu. Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492400858966.txt" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: roopa thank you again. Unfortunately it didn't work (I pasted your edited code and added back the background image) here: <http://jsbin.com/xisekajiqo/edit?output>
Footer is now not stuck at bottom and when you make the window smaller then larger again the footer completely disappears.

Comment: Actually content section height have fixed thats why footer is shifted in a above.

Comment: But i am trying to fixed your problems as soon as possible.

Comment: You should post answers with context, not just pieces of code, or you take the risk of getting downvoted.

Comment: Also; you're still answering the same question, so you should just update your original answer, instead of adding new answers